# PHP INSERT with array function

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, insert, implode

I am trying to insert the data in PHP with the array keys wise. I know how to insert data function when if data is single and without array. but this is an issue is comes first in my beginning PHP.
I have seen the other post with the `implode function but I couldn't understand that.

I am trying if product `123456` the QTY will insert `100` AND if product `123654` the QTY will `150` and other data will constantly insert.

**DATABASE STRUCTURE**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID |  SKU    |   PRODUCT    |   QTY   |  SUBJECT          | ANY_COMMENT |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 106101  |   123456     |   100   |  MY TEST SUBJECT  | MY_COMMENT  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 106101  |   123654     |   150   | MY TEST SUBJECT   | MY_COMMENT  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**PHP ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [subject] => MY TEST SUBJECT
    [sku] => 106101
    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123456
            [1] => 123654
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 150
        )

    [comment] =>MY_COMMENT
)
```

**PHP CODE**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `table` SET(`SKU`, `PRODUCT`, `QTY`, `SUBJECT`, `ANY_COMMENT`) VALUES(:sku, :product, :qty, :subject, :comment)");

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by binding parameters for each of your table columns; assign the constant values, and then iterate over the varying values in a loop, using the key into one array as the key for the other, and executing the statement on each pass through the loop. Something like this should work:

```php
// prepare statement
$stmt = $con->prepare("
INSERT INTO `table` (`SKU`, `PRODUCT`, `QTY`, `SUBJECT`, `ANY_COMMENT`) 
VALUES(:sku, :product, :qty, :subject, :comment)
");

// bind parameters
$stmt->bindParam(':sku', $sku, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':subject', $subject, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':product', $product, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':qty', $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// assign values and execute
$sku = $data['sku'];
$subject = $data['subject'];
$comment = $data['comment'];
foreach ($data['product'] as $key => $product) {
    $qty = $data['qty'][$key];
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "$product $qty\n";
}
```

Note that you don't need `SET` in that format of an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: thank its working but why `$MY_PRODUCT_VAR = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['product']))); $MY_PRODUCT_VAR = preg_replace(['/\s{2,}/', '/[\t\n]/'], ' ', $MY_PRODUCT_VAR);` not working for security purpose

Comment: @Satyam I'm not sure what you mean by "not working for security purpose"?

Comment: can I write like this `$sku = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($data['sku'])))`

Comment: @Satyam sure, you can, but if you're trying to ensure that the SKU is numeric or only contains numbers you should probably use something like [`ctype_digit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit) or perhaps ['filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var)

Comment: could me once last tell me how I check and add validation in `[qty]` error when any `key` empty

Comment: @Satyam If I understand you correctly, you could use `$qty = $data['qty'][$key] ?? 0;`

Comment: did you mean like this - `foreach ($data['product'] as $key => $product) {
    $qty = $data['qty'][$key];
    if($data['qty'][$key] == ' ') { echo "Qty is empty"} else { $stmt->execute(); }
}`

Comment: @Satyam it depends on whether you want to do an insert of a product if there is no associated quantity. If you do, use `foreach ($data['product'] as $key => $product) {     $qty = $data['qty'][$key] ?? 0;    $stmt->execute();  }`. If not, use `foreach ($data['product'] as $key => $product) {     if (isset($data['qty'][$key])) { $qty = $data['qty'][$key]; $stmt->execute(); } else { echo 'qty is empty!'; } }`